# Quicker searching in JScript using the Bash

Tags: javascript, bash, jscript

I am using the following JScript code to search for a string inside a file:

```
  var myFile = aqFile.OpenTextFile(fileToSearchIn, aqFile.faRead, aqFile.ctANSI);

  while(!myFile.IsEndOfFile())
  {
    s = myFile.ReadLine();
    if (aqString.Find(s, searchString) != -1)
      Log.Checkpoint(searchString + " found.", s); 
  }

  myFile.Close();
```

This is rather slow. I was thinking about using bash commands in order to speed up the search in file process:

```
  var WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
  var oExec = WshShell.Exec("C:\\cygwin\\bin\\bash.exe -c 'cat \"" + folderName + "/" + fileName + "\"'"); 
  while (!oExec.StdOut.AtEndOfStream)
    Log.Checkpoint(oExec.StdOut.ReadLine());
  while (!oExec.StdErr.AtEndOfStream)
    Log.Error(oExec.StdErr.ReadLine());
```

Since every time bash.exe is started a new window opens the searching is not faster than before. Is there a possibility to have the bash run in the background using another switch?

Answer (score 0):

Every invocation of `WshShell.Exec` will start a new process which is costly. If your textfile is not too big this will prevent spawning a new process:

```
var myFile = aqFile.OpenTextFile(fileToSearchIn, aqFile.faRead, aqFile.ctANSI);
var myFileData = myFile.Read(myFile.Size);
var index = myFileData.indexOf(searchString);
if(index>0)
{
  Log.Checkpoint(searchString + " found.", index); 
}
myFile.Close();
```

This will not print the whole line but the index of the found location. If you want the whole line, search for line endings from there.